# Minimize row width in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have a row in Bootstrap that contains several columns, and I want to add a shadow effect around the content to make the elements appear grouped up in a "card". The problem is that, when I add `shadow-sm` to the `className` property of the parent component of `Row`, the card appears extremely wide as the `Row` component stretches to both edges of the container. The content is not as wide as the row, so the current effect makes it appear loosely contained within the card. How can I make the row only take up as much space as it needs?

[Reference JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/flamesdev/b2f81ra5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bootstrap Sizing Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/).

Bootstrap Sizing Utilities are just Boostrap CSS classes to resize elements, In your case you will use width class which it will be `w-25`, `w-50`, `w-75`, `w-100` Or `w-auto`.

Comment: Adding `w-auto` doesn't seem to have any effect. I've edited my original post with a reference JSFiddle link; hopefully, that helps.